# Reorder string after split in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column with values like

```
xxxx-yyy-zzzzz-aaaaa-bbbbb
```

I need to split them on "-", and then concatenate in the order 4, 2, 0, 3, 1.

The result should be:

```
bbbbbzzzzzxxxxaaaaayyy
```

All in the same column.

Is there a way to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you would always expect five hyphen-separated items in the string, you could use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` with capture groups:

```sql
SELECT
    col,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(col, r'([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)', r'\5\3\1\4\2') AS col_out
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `r'([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)'` ?  anyway this is very simple and nice approach.

Comment: @Jaytiger Thanks for the correction, I answered on a cell phone.  +1 to your answer, which is canonical BigQuery syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider below as well

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG(part, '' ORDER BY o2) 
  FROM UNNEST(SPLIT('xxxx-yyy-zzzzz-aaaaa-bbbbb', '-')) part WITH OFFSET o1
  JOIN UNNEST([4, 2, 0, 3, 1]) seq WITH OFFSET o2 ON o1 = seq;
```

**Query results**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is the order always 4, 2, 0, 3, 1? Then this should work:

```sql
WITH v AS (
  SELECT
    'xxxx-yyy-zzzzz-aaaaa-bbbbb' as x
),
split_v AS (
  SELECT
    SPLIT(x, '-') as split_x
  FROM v
)
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    split_x[SAFE_OFFSET(4)],
    split_x[SAFE_OFFSET(2)],
    split_x[SAFE_OFFSET(0)],
    split_x[SAFE_OFFSET(3)],
    split_x[SAFE_OFFSET(1)]
  )
FROM split_v
```

Answer (score 0):

Showcasing the UDF in BQ, might not be the fastest solution always but easy to parameterize, standardize & improve over time

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  custom_split_reorg(c STRING,
    d STRING,
    o_arr ARRAY<INT64>)
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE js AS r"""
function custom(str, delim, order_arr) {
  var fin_str = "";
  const t_arr = str.split(delim);
  for(var i=0;i<t_arr.length;i++) {
    fin_str = fin_str + t_arr[order_arr[i]];
  }
  return fin_str;
}
return custom(c, d, o_arr);
""";
WITH
  TEMP AS (
  SELECT
    'xxxx-yyy-zzzzz-aaaaa-bbbbb' AS col1 )
SELECT
  col1,
  custom_split_reorg(col1,
    '-',
    [4,
    2,
    0,
    3,
    1]) AS result
FROM
  TEMP;
```

Result
[image]

Reference:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions